# ... Spread operator with already an array as parameter

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have this working code (puppeteer) :
￼

```
async function extractedEvaluateCall(page) {
    await page.waitForXPath(xpath);
    const links = await page.$x(xpath);
    const results = await page.evaluate((...links) => {
      return links.map(e => e.innerText);
    }, ...links);
}
```

What does the notation `...` does here ?

I tried without, it doesn't work:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON Are you passing a nested JSHandle?
```

**links is already an array, why the need of spread operator ?**

Comment: `links` is already an array, why the need of spread operator ?

Comment: It’ll destructure the array and pass the values as separate arguments to the function.

Comment: The first one is [Rest parameters syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and the second one is [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)?

Comment: @fubar there is no destructuring here. One is rest syntax and the other is spread syntax.